# Разница между созданием объекта со звездочкой и без

Tags: классы, указатели, c++

В чем разница между созданием объекта со звездочкой и без, кроме обращения не через точку, а через `->`?

Когда, к примеру, создаётся объект класса `SomeClass` через `Someclass obj`, то под него выделяется память, и будет как бы своя копия полей класса. А если создавать так: `Someclass *obj`, то под все его поля тоже выделится память? Получается что в обоих случаях создается объект и под него выделяется одинаковое количество памяти. А в чем тогда разница?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не-не-не, всё не так.

Текст

```
SomeClass obj1;
```

есть объявление переменной типа `SomeClass`. Для неё аллоцируется память размером в `sizeof(SomeClass)`: если объявление находится внутри функции, то на стеке, если в глобальной области, то выделяется глобальный объект.

Точно так же, текст

```
SomeClass* obj2;
```

есть объявление *указателя* типа `SomeClass*`. Для него аллоцируется 4 или 8 байт (или сколько там в вашей архитектуре), объект типа `SomeClass` при этом *не создаётся*. Для того, чтобы указатель имел смысл, надо присвоить ему адрес какого-нибудь объекта типа `SomeClass`. Например, можно создать этот объект в куче при помощи `new SomeClass` (при этом, понятно, выделится память), и присвоить полученный указатель переменной `obj2`.

Стало яснее?

Answer (score 5):

Неверно. Все неверно. Дело в том, что когда мы делаем так

> Someclass obj;

то мы конструируем экземпляр объекта. При этом он создается на стеке или в глобальной памяти и под него выделяется sizeof(Someclass) памяти.

Если же мы делаем так:

> Someclass *obj;

то мы создаем указатель. Принципиальной разницы от `void* obj` нет, кроме того, что компилятор будет проверять как мы будем этот указатель использовать и совсем уж явно бредовые варианты он нам реализовать не позволит. Но все равно ему можно объяснить, чтобы он заткнулся, если это действительно надо. Размер указателя зависит от типа платформы,под которую мы собираем программу. Но можно считать, что это 4 или 8 байт. При этом указатель - это по сути некий адрес в памяти. Не больше и не меньше. Пока мы этот указатель не привязали к объекту, ни к каким полям мы обратиться не сможем и никакие ф-ции члены вызвать тоже.

Т.е.

```
 Someclass *obj;
 obj->somefunc(); // сразу вызовет падение программы
```

Обычно же использует указатели так:

```
 Someclass obj;
 Someclass *pointer;
 pointer = &obj;
 pointer->somefunc(); // OK
 Someclass *pointer2 = new Someclass; // объявили указатель и сразу создали объект, а затем записали его адрес в указатель.
 pointer2->somefunc(); // тоже OK
```

Comment: +1, но `Someclass *obj; obj->somefunc();` вызывает в C++ не падение программы, а undefined behaviour (что существенно хуже).

Answer (score 3):

К приведённым выше ответом добавлю, что когда Вы объявляете указатель `Someclass *pointer;` а потом создаёте объект с помощью `new SomeClass(...`) например, то сам по себе объект хранится в куче, а указатель `pointer` на него в стеке - это очень важно понимать. Когда, происходит выход из функции стек "раскручивается" и этот указатель будет "уничтожен" (говоря простым языком), и будет утечка памяти (memory leak), если Вы её не освободили память через `delete pointer`.